I have upgraded the Angular Version 8,9,10 up to 16. Getting this error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element
I Have upgraded the Angular version 8,9,10 up to 16. On the Angular 16 facing the below issue. I have imported the all the material modules in the module file. then also it's giving the error.
In order to fix this issue. I tried below things

Imported all the modules in the required module file
Added CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA under the schemas.
Delete the node module folder and pacakge-lock.json file and reinstalled.
Cleared the cache
tsconfig.json updated.


Error: src/app/pages/layout/top-header/top-header/top-header.component.html:160:13 - error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
Error: src/app/pages/layout/top-header/top-header/top-header.component.html:158:9 - error NG8001: 'mat-sidenav-container' is not a known element:
If 'mat-sidenav-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If 'mat-sidenav-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.



Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

First you should need to verify the steps in upgrading guide here:
https://angular.dev/update-guide
When upgrading Angular, verify that you also need to upgrade the Angular Material, check if there is any breaking change for MatIconModule. I suppose you don't use standalone component yet so you need to put MatIconModule in the right module of your components. Usually this error happens when you upgrading Angular and some modules got renamed or move to a new path. Verify one by one and update accordingly the import.

Yes, I have followed the same step which is you given the link. And Declared, imported in the correct module. then also it's throwing the error.

Sound strange, delete node_modules, package-lock.json and reinstall everything. Can you try to follow the first guide of Angular Material 16 here: https://v16.material.angular.io/guide/getting-started ? Check if it work then remove the Angular Material elements in your template and add one by one, test if it works

Look like they drop mat-slidenav so you need to update your code using this guide
https://v16.material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples

I have followed this also but it's not worked. Still having the same error.

Sound weird, can you reproduce it with a small plunkr ?

If top-header component is standalone, add MatIconModule to the imports array.
@Component({
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
      ...
      MatIconModule,
      ...
    ],
    ...
})
export class TopHeaderComponent {
    ...

If the task is not standalone, go to the place where you declared the component declarations array. Then import MatIconModule.
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
      ...
      MatIconModule,
      ...
    ]
    ...
})
export class SomeModule {}


As you suggested same as I have already imported all the module in the respective modules file then also it's giving error.
